# Windows 11 shuts down when trying to boot from sleep or hibernate mode?

Tags: boot, windows-11, win10-fast-startup

My Dell Latitude 5530 seems to have a problem with Windows 11. It will boot and then shut down. When I power it on again it will boot properly into Windows. I figured it was the Fast Startup option in Windows 11 causing this, so I switched it off and now it boots properly on the first time.

However this odd problem remains while in sleep or hibernate mode. When I wake it up from sleep mode or start it after hibernation, it tries to boot, shuts down and then I have to power it on again and it always loads on the second time.

Any ideas, before I ditch this infamous OS?

Comment: Nothing major wrong with Windows 11 (3 machines here). Update BIOS and Power Drivers.  Reset Power Management to default. Disable Hibernate. Do a final restart and test.

Comment: I did all this, in fact I did every single step in this article: dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-bg/000129781/…. Still the problems persists.